# Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I want to compare two vectors, but the problem is one of the vectors that I extracted from a structure is a cell.

Example:

```
IN1 :[0] [0] [0] [1][0] [1] [0] [0] [1] [1] [0] 
IN2 :[0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
```

If I use

```
if IN1==IN2 disp('equal'); end
```

the error of undefined 'eq' for input arguments of type cell appears,
and if I replace `==` by `isequal(IN1,IN2)`, it doesn't give me the exact result.

I don't know how to convert the type of `IN1` to `IN2` or how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Try `[IN1{:}]==IN2`. This assumes both sides have the same size (or one of them has size 1). Another possibility would be `isequal([IN1{:}], IN2)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `IN1` into a numeric vector like `IN2`. For that, use `[IN1{:}]` or `mat2cell(IN1)`. *Then* you can compare. So, use

```
[IN1{:}]==IN2
```

or

```
cell2mat(IN1)==IN2.
```

This use of `==` assumes both sides have the same size, or one of them is a scalar. The result is a vector of the same size, containing `1` for elements that are equal `0` for elements that are different.

Another possibility would be

```
isequal([IN1{:}], IN2)
```

or

```
isequal(cell2mat(IN1), IN2)
```

This gives a single `1` if both sides have the same size and all their elements are equal, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

- `[IN1{:}] == IN2`
- `cell2mat(IN1) == IN2`
- `all([IN1{:}] == IN2)` if you want to compare the entire vector.